# Is there any harm in using the address of a parameter passed by reference to a function, inside the function?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

```
void func(Param& p1, Param& p2) {
   addObjectByPointer(&p1);
   addObjectByPointer(&p2);
}

int main() {
   Param p1;
   Param* p2 = new Param;
   func(p1, *p2);
}
```

Is there any harm in doing the above and hoping that the address of the original variable is returned? And assume we can happily passaround the pointer to the original object down the pipeline and access them anytime we like using the pointers?

Comment: It should be a simple experiment to print the values of all the pointers involved and verify this, yourself. Seems like this would be a very educational excersize, won't it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Except finding that one compiler does something is not complete justification for assuming the behavior is portable or guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: As long as you will not access them any more, after the function execution ends, yes.

Comment: Where does the function store the pointer? There is nothing wrong with taking the address via the reference, but just in the same way as you would need to if you were directly passing pointers, you must make sure that the stored pointer does not outlive the object. The function should document as clearly as possible what the lifetime of the pointer will be. And here that seems completely unclear.

Comment: `void func(std::unique_ptr<Param> p1, std::unique_ptr<Param> p2)` is a better signature for a "sink" function; ie pass me 2 heap allocated objects and I will take ownership of them both.

Comment: Technically, there is nothing wrong with your example but IMHO it bears a design weakness: `p1` will be deleted automatically at end of `main()`. `p2` will be never deleted. (It's memory is freed by the OS when the process ends but without calling the destructor.) Not a big issue in your MCVE but often in general applications. Where ever the pointers (passed in `addObjectByPointer()`) are stored - how should this code distinguish pointers which need to be `delete`d from the others?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` (suggested by @RichardCritten) has yet another advantage: You can provide a deleter. Hence, it can manage `p1` and `p2` while keeping the knowledge "on board" how to get rid of them. I once toyed with this: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae17e076a5a0830c)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Custom deleter can be stateful, even.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm but great deal of danger. The function does not control the lifetime of the object. By the time you use it again it might have been destroyed.

The general practice is that a function taking a raw pointer or reference will not store it. A function taking over ownership of a pointer will use `std::unique_ptr` instead and a function storing the pointer or reference will use `std::shared_ptr`.